# How to make a copy of an installed Ubuntu machine's packages, without internet access

Tags: ubuntu, apt, archive

I have an existing Ubuntu 12.04 server, with all the packages that I need in /var/cache/apt/archives.

I have a fresh install of 12.04 at a customer site with (deliberately) no internet access.

How can I install all the packages I need (from the first machine's apt archive), without messing up apt on the second machine.  (It may gain internet access later.)  I have a USB drive.

Will installing with dpkg do the job?  Would that mess up apt for future package installs?  How would I get the order of installing 100+ packages correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply copy all the `.deb` packages and install them with `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

There isn't any danger unless you forget some package or have the same package but with different versions. I would use APTonCD, or Apt-mirror, or [AptMedium](https://wiki.debian.org/AptMedium) as the safest methods.

There are a bunch of them in either:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/
- https://askubuntu.com/q/974/169736

Answer (score 2):

FIrst, I would use one of the tools Braiam described to put the the packages from the first server in a local repository on the second server. Next, I would run `dpkg --get-selections` on the first server, and feed it's output to `dpkg --set-selections` on the second server; that will mark software to be installed. FInally, I would run `apt-get dselect-upgrade` on the second server to peform the installation.